# Bootstrap navbar scrollspy with overflow-x menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow, navbar, sticky, scrollspy

I have done a bootstrap menu with scrollspy and sticky behaviour:

https://codepen.io/bodtx/pen/dyojeWb

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
        <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
        <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll</h3>
        <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
        <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</p>
      </div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse " data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#section5">Section 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section6">Section 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section7">Section 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section8">Section 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section9">Section 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section10">Section 10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section11">Section 11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section12">Section 12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section13">Section 13</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section14">Section 14</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section15">Section 15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section16">Section 16</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section17">Section 17</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section18">Section 18</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section19">Section 19</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section4" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 4</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section5" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 5</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section6" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 6</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>

      </div>
      <div id="section18" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 18</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="section19" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 19</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS

```
body {
      position: relative; 
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}

  /* Note: Try to remove the following lines to see the effect of CSS positioning */
  .affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
  }

  .affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }

.nav>.active>ul {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-nav li {

    display: inline-block;

}


ul.nav {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;

}

ul.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;

}
```

My menu can contain a lot of section (due to one long full page content), so I have a X scrollbar on my menu.

How could I scroll automatically on the correct menu entry when scrollspy highlight it.

for exemple if you scroll to section 18/19, we cannot see the highlighted item in the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, first I've changed the code of bootstrap.js to add a scrollIntoView action after the css "activation". but this is not the right way to do things.
After I've discovered the [bootstrap events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/#events)

then I've used a jquery selector on all my menu elements that scrollspy activate and do my scroll on this element:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            $('.navbar-nav li').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (e) {
                e.target.scrollIntoView();
            }
            );
        });
```

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#section1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1E88E5;
}

#section2 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #673ab7;
}

#section3 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff9800;
}

.sectionX {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff9800;
}

#section41 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00bcd4;
}

#section42 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #009688;
}

/* Note: Try to remove the following lines to see the effect of CSS positioning */
.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.affix+.container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
}

.nav>.active>ul {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-nav li {

    display: inline-block;

}


ul.nav {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;

}

ul.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="bootstrapSticky.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            $('.navbar-nav li').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (e) {
                e.target.scrollIntoView();
            }
            );
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
        <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
        <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll</h3>
        <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
        <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</p>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse " data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span
                                    class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#section5">Section 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section6">Section 6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section7">Section 7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section8">Section 8</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section9">Section 9</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section10">Section 10</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section11">Section 11</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section12">Section 12</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section13">Section 13</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section14">Section 14</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section15">Section 15</a></li>
                        <li id="menu16"><a href="#section16">Section 16</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section17">Section 17</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section18">Section 18</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section19">Section 19</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section4" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 4</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section5" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 5</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section6" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 6</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section7" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 7</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section8" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 8</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section9" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 9</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section10" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 10</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section11" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 11</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section12" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 12</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section13" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 13</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section14" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 14</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section15" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 15</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section16" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 16</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section17" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 17</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section18" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 18</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section19" class="container-fluid sectionX">
        <h1>Section 19</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and
            look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>





</body>

</html>
```